# Writing to a memory mapped region larger than system memory?

Tags: c++, windows, memory, memory-mapped-files

If I fully memory map a file larger than system memory and write to it faster than disk IO, what will happen?

Will I run out of system memory or will the writes to the memory mapped memory IO block?

Comment: Probably depends on buffering schemes, how you write, etc

Comment: I *believe* that in that case (some of) the already written-to pages will be written to the swap file in order to make room for new pages.

Comment: The writes will block.  But, of course, that can happen to ordinary memory too, if the OS has chosen to swap the page out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is OS-dependent, but it's perfectly possible for this to work out correctly. When the OS memory-maps a file, it doesn't have to eagerly load the contents into memory and can lazily fetch the pages when a read or write occurs in that region. In other words, any time you try to access bytes from the file, the OS can page in that region and page out other parts of the file (or pages from other programs) to make it look as though the data was there all along. This might lead to some program slowdown due to paging, but it doesn't have to crash or lock up the system.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, that makes sense for reading. However, for writes I was guessing that it caches as much of the writes as possible in memory when IO is not keeping up? Not sure what the write cache strategy is.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming [MapViewOfFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366761%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will let you map a *view* of the file larger than available memory, I would expect that some of your reads and writes will stall until the page fault can be resolved.  Thus you will be limited to the available I/O bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

You're mistakingly assuming that you can "write faster than disk I/O".

Since your mapping exceeds RAM, there will be pages not in RAM. Writing to them will cause a non-fatal fault. The OS handles the fault by suspending your thread, freeing memory by writing out another page and then paging in the relevant part of the file. Only when the I/O finishes is your thread resumed.

So, your thread cannot outrun disk I/O as it's constantly waiting for disk I/O to finish.

Of course, if memory is available, you benefit from not having to free dirty pages. But you still block on the reads. After all, memory mapping works on a page base, and the CPU can't write a whole page in one instruction. Thus every write is necessarily a read-modify-write operation on a page.